# Can I safely mount a wall-mount networking rack on one stud?

Tags: concrete, studs, cinderblock

So I never really thought of it but I put a wall mount hinged Networking Rack in my home, it never came across my head "how much can this stud hold?"

Image of the wall and rack:

[image]

Ignore the mess inside the rack, I'm gonna clean that up and make it look really nice later just needed to wrap it up for couple days.

But my question is, is there a certain rule of thumb that a construction worker has to follow when mounting studs to a cinderblock wall? 
I'm little worried of this thing falling off the wall in the middle of night. I was able to hang on it with the rack and I'm 200lb and it didn't budge but I'm still worried that it may weaken. Any thought will be helpful!

PS the studs don't extend to the ground.

Comment: How did you attach the "stud" to the wall?

Comment: @Tester101 the people who built the house installed it

Comment: Is it a wooden 2x4 stud or something else (2x6, metal stud, etc.)? How is the rack attached to the stud itself?

Comment: @haimg It's a 2x4 stud that and the plywood board is nailed into the studs. I mounted 2 lag bolts into the stud with the server rack then then 6 of them are in the plywood board

Comment: That's cool someone edited my title that doesn't even match the topic.

Comment: What you have is a vertically oriented length of  2 x 4 lumber (how long?) attached to a cinder block wall and not resting on the floor below, with a piece of plywood nailed to it.  The method of attachment of the 2 x 4 to the wall is presumably hidden by the plywood and unknown to you.  Unless you know how the 2 x 4 is attached to the wall, you cannot know whether it is safe or not. Probably it is. Did you install the plywood? If so, do you remember how many and what type of fastener was used to attach the 2 x 4 to the wall?

Comment: Does the plywood extend onto other vertical members attached to the wall? If so, then the plywood would distribute part of the load onto other vertical members.

Comment: @JimStewart It was attached by the builders. That's why I am not as worried but like you said I'm unsure what they use to fasten it. But if I had to guess they probably used the same mounting stuff they used on the other stud that's holding power outlet Image of it here: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aq0jVgVMqDVijs1SsdHLIxH9stN06A

Comment: @JimStewart and yes there are two 2x4

Comment: The fastener appears to be a type of rectangular cross section nail that has been hammered into the mortar joints between the blocks.  AFIK these are not designed to resist pullout. Personally, I think it very unlikely with the load you have that it would come down without warning, Just my personal opinion. But if it would collapse without warning with a child underneath, then . . . But drilling holes for anchors for serious fasteners could damage something in the wall.

Comment: @JimStewart yeah I think your right. And also it would show warning like you said and on top of that it would have to take down both 2x4. Prior from me putting the rack there they had heavy duty shelving mounted to it. So I mean they were expecting some kind of weight load. Also I was able to hang on the stud on the right for good 10-15s and there was no sign of budging or moving. I think I just needed to talk it over with someone to ease my anxiety. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it all hinges on whether 2x4s are mounted to the wall securely, and you have no simple way to verify that. In any case, since they do not extend all the way to the floor, they are not structural, and were not designed to handle any kind of a serious load.

I'd say the most simple way to to address this would be this:

1. Go to a home improvement center (home depot, etc.), get 4 sleeve anchors, 1/2" x 3" at least, which are rated for cinder blocks. If your 2x4 boards are attached to the wall with their narrow edge, you'll need way longer bolts, you need at least several inches in the cinder blocks.
2. Drill 4 holes, 2 into each of these 2x4 members, staggering the holes and keeping well away from the edges, into the upper half of these boards, using wood drill bit.
3. Drill into the cinder blocks using concrete drill bit, for the length and diameter appropriate for the fasteners that you bought.
4. Install the anchors, do not over-tighten.

There are many ways to attach a board to a cinder block wall (tapcons, concrete anchors, etc.), they all will work well. Basically what I'm saying is that if you can't be sure these boards are attached securely enough, just add more fasteners that will definitely support the load.

Here, I presume that your rack is securely mounted to the wood (real lag bolts, not some drywall screws), you'll want to inspect that as well.

Comment: Thank you and yes as far as the rack it self its secured. I will most certainly do what you suggested.